# How can I set up port forwarding on a Huawei HG8546M router

Tags: port-forwarding

> Blockquote

Has anyone done this successfully? I've read all the documents but keep getting an error that the external source end port is not valid. I don't know what the setting should be.

I want to ssh to a home[image] server on port 2222

Comment: Can you provide screenshots?

Comment: I'm on my phone. Not easy to get a full screenshot

Comment: We need the full configuration page...What you have provided is not helpful.

Comment: [Here is a page which contains a full screenshot of the configuration menu, as well as an explanation for every item](https://forum.huawei.com/enterprise/en/huawei-ont-basics-7-how-to-configure-port-mapping-on-huawei-ont/thread/590900-100181)

Comment: I think you have an error in the router model. And we need a full screenshot of your router screen to really see what you're doing.